# New tag [tag:probability-limit-theorems]

Tags: discussion, tags

Created just now [probability-limit-theorems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-limit-theorems)

I just copied from here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/probability-limit-theorems/info

What do you think?

Comment: What problem do you imagine this tag solves that is not solved by the existing tags?

Comment: Our policy is to grow tags organically, typically by letting new questions suggest their need.  Sometimes, a collection of existing questions about related matters will suggest a new tag; at other times, it becomes clear that an existing tag is overloaded and needs to be disambiguated by creating one or more new related tags.  Could you please explain what your reason is for creating this tag?

Comment: @whuber you don't think maths se has *more* use for this highly specific tag than stats se does do you? sounds like having a [catholic se](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/) that doesn't have say catholic canon law tag while christianity se does. or do you mean the analogy is that there can be even further specific tags than catholic canon law namely all the probability limit theorems? well 1 thing i had in mind is like [i had a feeling some limit theorem applied but i didn't know which 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/560742)

Comment: We are not the math site.  The existence (or absence) of a tag on that site is irrelevant for us.  BTW, it's not a good sign that the one post you reference in support of your tag proposal has been closed!

Comment: We also lack a tag for `statistics`: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics which seems to dramatically undercut your argument from analogy about Catholicism.

Answer (score 7):

Relevant tags currently in use include [asymptotics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptotics) (701 questions, broader than just limit theorems), [convergence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convergence) (990 questions, also applicable to solutions found by iterative algorithms), [central-limit-theorem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/central-limit-theorem) (705 questions, concerning a particular limit theorem of especial fame), & [law-of-large-numbers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law-of-large-numbers) (135 questions, ditto). There's a *prima facie* case for reorganization, but it's not evident that simply throwing [probability-limit-theorems](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-limit-theorems) into the mix will help.

Answer (score 5):

At an absolute minimum, it needs a short and long description, just as every other tag does.